# How to set default line endings in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, line-endings

I have an autosetting for Windows somewhere (CRLF) which is really annoying, is there a way to change this to Unix?

Comment: Search for `eol` in the settings.  There is a default setting there.

Answer (score 65):

Search for EOL in VScode settings and click on '\n' to make LF default.

[image]

Comment: The title says *Also modified elsewhere*. Where is it?

Comment: @smwikipedia Hover the mouse pointer above the text "(Modified elsewhere)" and a popup will appear that states where the setting is modified.

Comment: It works, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Open VS code window then Ctrl+Shift+P to open settings and search for EOL like @David Bakare suggested above.